# How to specify the expected structure of an input object?

Tags: javascript, node.js, documentation

I find myself using a lot of functions similar to the following in NodeJS:

```
socket.on('view:create', function (data) {
    //data = { structure of data object here }
    ....
})
```

I am basically adding a comment to remember what is the data object.

How can I specify the structure of the object I am receiving as input, so that when inside the function I write `data.key` it recognizes the key as valid?

Comment: So that what recognizes `key` as valid? Node.js? [Member operators](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Member_Operators) don't `throw` for unset properties, they return `undefined`. Are you wanting to validate the object so you can `emit` an error?

Comment: NodeJS is just an example. I guess.. the editor? I am using WebStorm. 
What I would like in general is a way to add a bit of "strictness". Since we cannot have clear objects like in Java, it would be good to manually specify "how the object should be".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use the commenting style advised for [Google Closure](https://developers.google.com/closure/compiler/docs/js-for-compiler).

It is very similar to the style of different languages, helps autocompletion in modern IDEs, and with [JsDoc](https://github.com/jsdoc3/jsdoc) generating documentation from it is also easy.

For your example, this would do the trick:

```
@param {{myNum: number, myObject}}
```

Comment: Woah! Nice! 

`@param {{myNum: number, myObject}}` seems exactly what I was looking for!

Comment: definitely the solution.. even though I cannot seem to make it work in WebStorm (which should support it.. meh)

Comment: I'm using PhpStorm and it supports this documentation style

Comment: Yep, there is a problem with anonymous functions, but naming them it works like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you could use a default object and than extended it with your object:

```
function( my_object ){
  ...
  var default_object = {
    a: 1,
    b: 2
  }

  _.extend( default_object, my_object ); // underscore _.extend

  default_object.a // always defined
  ...
}
```

or you could explode your object and use comma separated arguments in your function:

```
function( arg1, args2, /*, other_args */ ){
  var other_args = [].slice.call(arguments, 2);
}
```

Comment: definitely an option, but I'll look into Google Closure Commenting style.. seems promising